# How does the user account used at installation affect who can use the program?

Tags: user-accounts

So lets say I am a user for this machine and I installed a program - example a game. Will the other user using same machine also be able to use that program?

Should that program be installed while logged in as an admin or can I just user my user account to install with the admin credentials?

Comment: This depends entirely on the operating system and the precise installation steps you performed. Typically modern OSes offer a way to install using admin credentials even if you run the installer as a regular user, but there are many factors which may or may not affect this. This is probably too broad to get a decent answer as it is.

Comment: "Pls advise and also share any sites that have good articles regards to user accounts." - Questions seeking learning material are out of scope here at Superuser.  There is not a StackExchange website at this time where questions seeking learning material would be within scope.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  As the previous comments indicate, your question was out of scope and would likely have been closed.  I focused it on your main question, although you should add additional detail such as your OS.  There are still a lot of possible variations, though, so the more detail you can add, the better.  You can ask your other questions as additional, individual questions, but limit each one to a single, specific question that's on-topic for the site.